# Append a new item to a list within a list

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to append a new float element to a list within another list, for example:

```
list = [[]]*2
list[1].append(2.5)
```

And I get the following:

```
print list
[[2.5], [2.5]]
```

When I'd like to get:

```
[[], [2.5]]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As agf points out below, it's best to avoid using `list` as a variable name, because it's normally the name of the built-in list type.

Comment: Often "lst" is used for ease of use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`lst = [[] for _ in xrange(2)]` (or just `[[], []]`). Don't use multiplication with mutable objects — you get the same one X times, not X different ones.

Comment: I'd reccomend not using `_` as apparently it can mess up some interactive interpreters. Also, don't call it `list`, you're masking the builtin. Also, you'll get the same one X times for immutable objects too, it just doesn't often matter, unless you later want to check object identity.

Comment: @ag: `_` is standard "I don't care about this variable" variable. It is used by the interactive mode to store the last result, but it certainly doesn't mess anything up.

Comment: I know what it's used for. I forget now, but I believe it messes up tracebacks in one of the IDEs.

Comment: @agf: Then that is a bug of that IDE. Common codestyle is more important, to me, at least.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus *underscore* often used as translator in multilingual applications, so it's bad practice to use it unless you never work on such a projects

Comment: C'mon you can find so many more options. At the biggest case, use... I don't know.. max. (disclaimer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: A note since this question has many views: in Python3+, use `range(2)` instead of `xrange(2)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
list_list = [[] for Null in range(2)]
```

dont call it `list`, that will prevent you from calling the built-in function `list()`.

The reason that your problem happens is that Python creates **one list** then repeats it twice. So, whether you append to it by accessing it either with `list_list[0]` or with `list_list[1]`, you're doing the same thing so your changes will appear at both indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You can do in simplest way....

```
>>> list = [[]]*2
>>> list[1] = [2.5]
>>> list
[[], [2.5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [[]]
list.append([2.5])
```

or

```
list = [[],[]]
list[1].append(2.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is a list constructor, and in `[[]]` a list and a sublist is constructed. The `*2` duplicates the reference to the inner list, but no new list is constructed:

```
>>> list[0] is list[1]
... True
>>> list[0] is []
... False
```

The solution is to have 2 inner lists, `list = [[], []]`

Answer (score 2):

As per @Cat Plus Plus dont use multiplication.I tried without it.with same your code.

```
>> list = [[],[]]
>> list[1].append(2.5)
>> list
>> [[],[2.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write something like this:

```
>>> l = [[] for _ in xrange(2)]
>>> l[1].append(2.5)
>>> l
[[], [2.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outter list contains another list and multiplying the outter list will have the resulting list's items all have the same pointer to the inner list.
You can create a multidimensional list recursively like this:

```
def MultiDimensionalList(instance, *dimensions):
    if len(dimensions) == 1:
      return list(
         instance() for i in xrange(
          dimensions[0]
        )
      )
    else:
      return list(
        MultiDimensionalList(instance, *dimensions[1:]) for i
        in xrange(dimensions[0])
      )

print MultiDimensionalList(lambda: None, 1, 1, 0)
```

> [[]]

Comment: But allows you to create a list of any dimension.

Comment: Of course! Over-engineered stuff usually lets you do "cool" things, but most of it is not needed with regard to the initial requirements ;-)