# append value in ith list of list

Tags: list, python-2.7, append

I have b which is a list and it further contains 10 lists in it, every index of list contains list itself. now, when I try to append some value in ith list o b, it appends it in all list. I don't understand why? help.

**CODE:**

```
a=[3,5,1,7,2,22,9,8,4,11]
b=[[]]*10
d=10
for i in range(len(a)):         
    b[i].append(a[i])
    print b
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
>   [[3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5]]
>   [[3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7], [3, 5, 1, 7]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4]]
>   [[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11], [3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 22, 9, 8, 4, 11]]

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814727/append-a-new-item-to-a-list-within-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't intialize as a mutable object as this post suggests: [Append a new item to a list within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814727/append-a-new-item-to-a-list-within-a-list)

Instead, rewrite the list as:

```
>>> b=[[] for _ in xrange(10)]
>>> b
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> b[0].append(0)
>>> b
[[0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

For the code you have given,

```
a=[3,5,1,7,2,22,9,8,4,11]
b=[[] for _ in xrange(10)]
d=10;
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i].append(a[i])
    print b
```

Output:

```
[[3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [2], [], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [2], [22], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [2], [22], [9], [], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [2], [22], [9], [8], [], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [2], [22], [9], [8], [4], []]
[[3], [5], [1], [7], [2], [22], [9], [8], [4], [11]]
```